# Change the background or class in table row

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I use http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/

Need an example of how to change of the class of the table row in function of custom field value

I use this for single cell

```
cellStyle: function(value){
                    if(value=='0'){
                        return { classes: 'success' };
                    }else{
                        return { classes: 'danger' };
                    }               
                },
```

And I get this
[image]

But I need this
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: just see sample for [rowStyle](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/#style-rowstyle)

Comment: Can you give me an example in JavaScript to change rowStyle in the function of the field "Read", based on this https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/221 for cellStyle

Comment: i not quite understand what you mean here: _change rowStyle in the function of the field "Read"_? can you explain?

Comment: do you mean - check value in cell _Read_ and set style depends on it?

Comment: Yes that's what I thought

Comment: ok, wait a minute :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first parameter in `rowStyle` function is data object for current row. You can simple check property for that output in `Read` column and return needed classes.

```
function rowStyle(row, index) {

    if(row.Read = 100){ // possibly you map another property, it depends on your setting.

        return {classes : "neededClass" }
    }
    return {};
}
```

sample [JS fiddle with test data](http://jsfiddle.net/s3aL4m5y/)